# Python - communicating with subprocess over a socket

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I am looking to replicate the way programs like Git and Rsync communicate and transfer data over an SSH connection, but in Python. I understand that these programs fork and exec an SSH command that starts a process on the server side and communication is achieved by the parent processing talking to the STDIN and STDOUT of the forked child process.

In C I have seen this done by creating a Unix socket pair (s0, s1), forking the process, pointing the stdin/stdout of the forked process to s1 on the child process, and then reading and writing to the socket s0 on the parent process.

I want to do the same thing in Python3. As a proof of concept, here is my implementation of a toy remote shell that sends commands down a socket and receives the output from the same socket:

```
import subprocess
import socket


ssh_cmd = 'ssh -q -T ubuntu@xxxxxxxx'
s_local, s_remote = socket.socketpair(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

ssh = subprocess.Popen(ssh_cmd, shell=True,
                       stdout=s_remote,
                       stdin=s_remote,
                       close_fds=True)
s_remote.close()

s_local.send('ls -l\n'.encode())
print(s_local.recv(1024).decode())
s_local.send('uname -a\n'.encode())
print(s_local.recv(1024).decode())
s_local.close()
ssh.kill()
```

This kind of works. But I can deadlock it if I send 'true \n' down the socket because 'recv' is blocking so that's not great.

1. Is this a sensible/common thing to do in network programming?
2. What is a more idiomatic way of doing this using the Python3 standard libraries that doesn't deadlock?

Comment: What you're trying to do is quite sensible. You may want to investigate the `pexpect` module. It is tailor-made for this kind of thing: driving an interactive application.  See https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html for a good start. It also has the ability to put timeouts on your interactions in case you're expecting a response but get none.

Comment: Your example code has both stdin and stdout set to s_remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I connected a web browser to the `stdin` and `stdout` of a command running on the remote end of a SSH connection. It sounds like you're trying to do something similar: connect a socket to a program running on a remote machine so that clients can connect to a host/port and use said remote program.

The first thing you need to do is establish a SSH connection. I use an external `ssh` program (either `ssh` or `plink` depending on OS) in a subprocess. You could just use class `subprocess.Popen` to do that. The subprocess launches the (external) `ssh` application to connect to the remote host and runs the required command. That then sits there listening on its 'stdin' and willing to reply on its 'stdout'.

(You could possibly use Python SSH implementation such as Paramiko here)

**At a very high level** (where `remote_command` is the thing to run on the far end):

```
import subprocess
command = ['ssh', 'user@host', 'remote_command']

sproc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False,
                         stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

This leaves you with a subprocess that you can interact with through its `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`.

**Get this bit working first.**

The next thing you need is to bind a socket, listen and accept a connection. Then read from the client and write to the server. I wrote a lightweight `Socat` (inspired by [Socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat)) class:

```
import socket

class Socat(object):

EOT = '\004\r\n'

def __init__(self, binding, stream, eot = EOT):

  self.stream = stream
  self.eot = eot

  self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  self.socket.bind(binding)
  self.socket.listen(5)

  while True:
    print "waiting for connection"
    (clientsocket, address) = self.socket.accept()
    print "connection from %s:%s" % address
    data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    self.stream.write(data)
    while data:
      data = self.stream.readline()
      if data:
        print "read %s bytes" % len(data)
        if data == self.eot:
          print "read termination signature"
          clientsocket.close()
          data = None
        else:
          clientsocket.send(data)
```

You should read up on Sockets: [this](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html) and [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) are useful here.

You can then use this to connect to your `remote_command`:

```
Socat( ('localhost', 8080), sproc)
```

**There are some missing bits**

You'll notice the `socat` class takes in a `stream` (unlike my example) that has `write` and `readline` methods. I actually encapsulated the SSH connection in a class but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader!

(Basically a `class Stream` that contains the `sproc` and provides `write` and `readline` methods - effectively `sproc.stdin.write()` and `sproc.stdout.readline()` - you get the idea!)

Also, you need a protocol to allow `remote_command` to signal the end of a transmission. I used the ASCII `EOT` character and my remote program sends that at the end of a response. The `socat` uses that to close the client connection and accept a new one. Depending on your use-case you will need to come up with a protocol that works for you.

**Finally**

All of the above can be improved upon. What's above is my first cut because it is simple to see the inner workings. I have since extended it to run the accept loop in a thread and gracefully handle disconnects and so-on.

But hopefully what's above is a reasonable starting point.